# Update values using multiple columns from one table and a single column from another table

Tags: r, sql-server, sql-update, sqldf

I have the following table `lc`:

```
a   b   c   d 
co  NA  co  1
co  NA  co  84
us  co  us  6
NA  co  NA  54
us  NA  NA  4
```

And another table `ro`

```
d   value
bb  1
co  0.5
mn  0.03
us  2
```

I want to update the values in `lc` with the values in `ro` to get the following:

```
a    b    c    d 
0.5  NA   0.5  1
0.5  NA   0.5  84
2    0.5  2    6
NA   0.5  NA   54
2    NA   NA   4
```

I have the code:

```
lc <- sqldf(c("UPDATE lc SET a = (SELECT ro.value FROM ro WHERE lc.a = ro.d)",
    "SELECT * FROM main.lc")
    )
```

And that obviously updates only the column `a`, but not the others. How can I update the remaining columns in the same statement?
I have looked at posts that address the UPDATE query in SQL, but all of them just compare one column from one table to one column from another table.

This is just an example, I actually have 40 columns to be updated in `lc` with millions of rows and `a` `b` `c` values can be different from `co` and `us`, so I need it to be very efficient.

Comment: are you looking for a sql solution or any r solution?

Comment: any solution that works within r. I started to use sql because I thought it would be more efficient due to the amount of data I am dealing with

Comment: You'll be replacing `character` columns with `numeric` columns, is that what you intend? (Just making sure ... you cannot do a partial on this, the conversion must be all or none.)

Comment: yes, `character` to `numeric`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this below script-

```
SELECT B.value a,C.value b,D.value c, A.d 
FROM lc A
LEFT JOIN ro B ON A.a = B.d
LEFT JOIN ro C ON A.b = C.d
LEFT JOIN ro D ON A.C = D.d
```

Output is-

```
a       b       c       d
0.50    NULL    0.50    1
0.50    NULL    0.50    84
2.00    0.50    2.00    6
NULL    0.50    NULL    54
2.00    NULL    NULL    4
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not very familiar with SQL, what are the capital letters `B`, `C` and `D` referring to?

Comment: Those are aliases I have set for table ro three times. They are basically referring table ro. As I joined the same table 3 times, I just gave 3 separate Alias name.

Comment: A refereeing table lc and B/C/D  refereeing table ro.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So if I have 20 values in table `ro` I would have to join 20 times?

Comment: Nope, no mater how many values are there in table ro. You have 3 column in table lc that required update and as a result I joined the table ro 3 times. That's should be enough for your purpose. Just make sure table ro has no duplicate values in column d. other wise row count will increase.

Comment: Guess I already understood. I have 40 columns in `lc` so I would have to create 40 different aliases for `ro` and join 40 times. Am I right?

Comment: Unfortunately yes :( you have to establish 40 joins. But there might have some other solutions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197956/discussion-between-janf-and-mkrabbani).

Answer (score 0):

With `base R`, we use a named vector to match the values in the character columns in 'lc' and replace those values with the correpsonding 'value' from 'ro'

```
lc[1:3] <- setNames(ro$value, ro$d)[as.matrix(lc[1:3])]
lc
#    a   b   c  d
#1 0.5  NA 0.5  1
#2 0.5  NA 0.5 84
#3 2.0 0.5 2.0  6
#4  NA 0.5  NA 54
#5 2.0  NA  NA  4
```

#### data

```
lc <- structure(list(a = c("co", "co", "us", NA, "us"), b = c(NA, NA, 
"co", "co", NA), c = c("co", "co", "us", NA, NA), d = c(1L, 84L, 
6L, 54L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

ro <- structure(list(d = c("bb", "co", "mn", "us"), value = c(1, 0.5, 
0.03, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```